# Ask pattern which doesn't wait after result

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, actor

I have an akka actor which is doing some things sequentially, it can be summarized like that :

```
def receive = {
    case Request(...) => {
        val id = generatedId()
        sender() ! id
        doSomeOtherStuffs()
    }
}
```

The actor is called using some *ask* pattern

```
val id = myActor ? Request(...)
```

The problem here is the code calling my actor is waiting for all of the `doSomeOtherStuffs()` thing to complete.

What is the correct way to allow an actor to reply and then have the calling code stop waiting for that actor ?

Comment: I don't think the client (specifically, the `ask`/`?` call) should be waiting for `doSomeOtherStuffs()` to complete, it should be able to continue (i.e., the future should complete) as soon as it gets the `id`. Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: I'm not an expert in akka, but I guess such things may happen if you have custom thread pool configuration with only one thread available in the pool.

Comment: Why do you want the sender to wait for the result from doSomeOtherStuffs() while you already sent them the id?
1. Because you sent back the id, so the sender will not wait for anything more. This is correct corresponding to your written code.
2. If that's really what you want. Why dont you send back the id to sender after doSomeOtherStuffs() complete its job only?

Answer (score -1):

How about this? Decouple the actual execution of other stuff from answering the Request

```scala
def receive = {
    case Request(...) => {
        val id = generatedId()
        sender() ! id
        self ! DoSomethingElse(...)
    }
    case DoSomethingElse(...) =>
        doSomethingElse()
}
```